# Whats the best way to create an array of objects inside a class as attribute in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, class

So I have hard time figuring out the best way and the correct way to do this, so I'm posting this question if someone can help me here, as I'm doing a Laravel project in PHP.

So lets imagine we are building an app for books, each book have several pages, some have 20 and some might have 700, if we were to create a class, or classes for these books correctly, how do we do that?

Below I have few ways to go about it, but I don't know what would work, and/or what is the best one.

Option 1:

```
<?php
namespace Translation/Logic;

public class Book {
  // atributes
  public $title;
  public $year;
  public $author;
  public $description;
  public $date;
  public $language = "English";

  // as an atribute maybe we need to have an array of pages here? like
  // public $pages = Pages[]??
}

public class Pages {
   public number;
   public orientation;
   public direction;
   public page;
   public chapter;
   public content;

}
```

Option 2:

```
<?php
namespace Translation/Logic;

abstract class Book {
  // atributes
  public $title;
  public $year;
  public $author;
  public $description;
  public $date;
  public $language = "English";

  // as an attributes maybe we need to have an array of pages here? 
}

public class Pages extends Book {
   public number;
   public orientation;
   public direction;
   public page;
   public chapter;
   public content;

}
// Then create an array of Pages here, but then we have all the attributes of the books in every page, which don't really make sense?
```

I'm pretty sure I'm going about it the wrong way here, and there is a smarter way to do this, but just need a little help here.

If it is one of my solution, what is the code that should complete my code, also is there any alternative ways other than mine, and what will be the pros and cons of each one.

If not and I'm wrong, what is then the correct way to define these classes, and why?

Thanks for taking the time to answer me :)

Comment: If you're using Laravel, use Models. You'd have a `Book` model, a `Page` model, and the database would support a one-to-many structure between them (where a Book can have one or more Pages). All of these attributes (like page, direction, chapter, content, etc) would be database columns.

Comment: True, and I will use Models, but then again if I wanted to load the data of a book from the Model into a class object, for manipulations etc.. it would be nice and neat to also be able to do that, and thats why the question.

Comment: That would be done with models; `public function pages()`, and all you'd have to do is call `$book->pages`, and you'd have a Collection of Page models for a specific book: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. And by default, all the properties of a Book are loaded when you query the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim Lewis says in the comments to his question, the best way to do this is with Eloquent models.

Let me give you a quick example of how the best way to do this.

This would be his **Book class**.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'year', 'author', 'description', 'date', 'language'];

    /**
    * Get the pages of this book.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    */
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page');
    }

}
```

This would be his **Page class**.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['number', 'orientation', 'direction', 'page', 'date', 'chapter', 'content'];

    /**
    * Get the book of this page.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    */
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
    }

}
```

So if you want to get all **books with all your pages** you would have to do it in a controller like this.

```
$books = Book::with('pages')->get();
```

If you just want to get **a book with your pages**.

```
$book = Book::with('pages')->first();
```

Comment: Nice summary! And you're almost there, but the way you described the difference between `Book::with('pages')->get()` and `Book::with('pages')->first()` isn't quite right. The difference is that  `Book::with('pages')->get()` will return "all books in the database with all of their pages", while `Book::with('pages')->first()` will return "the first book in the database with all of its pages". I.e. both load all of the pages :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to explain, clearly if you don't want to get the first one from the database simply do a where before the ```first```. It's just a simple example.

Comment: Thank you all, in fact this seems to work, **Eloquent models** is the answer here